# Add (insert) a column between two columns in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, insert

I have a data frame that has columns a, b, and c. I'd like to add a new column d between b and c.

I know I could just add d at the end by using *cbind* but how can I **insert** it in between two columns?

Comment: Maybe this does what you want: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-insert-a-column-in-a-data-frame-td883724.html

Comment: does the mutate() function in dplyr package allow to add columns as stated in this question?

Answer (score 118):

I would suggest you to use the function `add_column()` from the [`tibble`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/index.html) package.

```
library(tibble)
dataset <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 2:6, c=3:7)
add_column(dataset, d = 4:8, .after = 2)
```

Note  that you can use column names instead of column index :

```
add_column(dataset, d = 4:8, .after = "b")
```

Or use argument `.before` instead of `.after` if more convenient.

```
add_column(dataset, d = 4:8, .before = "c")
```

Comment: I removed the name-dropping. Doesn't seem to add much, and while Hadley is listed as *an* author of the package Kirill Müller is listed as [creator and maintainer](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/index.html).

Answer (score 54):

Add in your new column:

```
df$d <- list/data
```

Then you can reorder them.

```
df <- df[, c("a", "b", "d", "c")]
```

Comment: I find reordering using `setcolorder` in conjunction with column numbers (as opposed to their names) to also be very useful, because once the number of columns becomes very large, you can start using `seq` and `rep`to do most of the work. Plus arithmetic operators can be used. E.g. `setcolorder(data, c(1, (num_cols -2), (num_cols -1), num_cols, seq(from = 2, to = (num_cols - 3))))`

Comment: I should mention, `setcolorder` is meant for a data.table, not a data.frame!

Answer (score 25):

You can reorder the columns with [, or present the columns in the order that you want.

```
d <- data.frame(a=1:4, b=5:8, c=9:12)
target <- which(names(d) == 'b')[1]
cbind(d[,1:target,drop=F], data.frame(d=12:15), d[,(target+1):length(d),drop=F])

  a b  d  c
1 1 5 12  9
2 2 6 13 10
3 3 7 14 11
4 4 8 15 12
```

Comment: This is a great answer.  But I have to admit, this is also a great example of why R can be difficult for beginners.

Comment: That being said, I think @ashah57  has a much simpler and cleaner answer below. No need to get too fancy on something like this.

Answer (score 17):

Presuming that `c` always immediately follows `b`, this code will add a column after `b` no matter where `b` is in your data.frame.

```
> test <- data.frame(a=1,b=1,c=1)
> test
  a b c
1 1 1 1

> bspot <- which(names(test)=="b")

> data.frame(test[1:bspot],d=2,test[(bspot+1):ncol(test)])
  a b d c
1 1 1 2 1
```

Or possibly more naturally:

```
data.frame(append(test, list(d=2), after=match("b", names(test))))
```

Answer (score 8):

Create an example data.frame and add a column to it.

```
df = data.frame(a = seq(1, 3), b = seq(4,6), c = seq(7,9))
df['d'] <- seq(10,12)
df

  a b c  d
1 1 4 7 10
2 2 5 8 11
3 3 6 9 12
```

Rearrange by column index

```
df[, colnames(df)[c(1:2,4,3)]]
```

or by column name

```
df[, c('a', 'b', 'd', 'c')]
```

The result is

```
  a b  d c
1 1 4 10 7
2 2 5 11 8
3 3 6 12 9
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a quick and dirty way of inserting a column in a specific position on a data frame. In my case, I have 5 columns in the original data frame: `c1, c2, c3, c4, c5` and I will insert a new column `c2b` between `c2` and `c3`.

1) Let's first create the test data frame:

```
> dataset <- data.frame(c1 = 1:5, c2 = 2:6, c3=3:7, c4=4:8, c5=5:9)
> dataset
  c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
1  1  2  3  4  5
2  2  3  4  5  6
3  3  4  5  6  7
4  4  5  6  7  8
5  5  6  7  8  9
```

2) Add the new column `c2b` at the end of our data frame:

```
> dataset$c2b <- 10:14
> dataset
  c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c2b
1  1  2  3  4  5  10
2  2  3  4  5  6  11
3  3  4  5  6  7  12
4  4  5  6  7  8  13
5  5  6  7  8  9  14
```

3) Reorder the data frame based on column indexes. In my case, I want to insert the new column (6) between existing columns 2 and 3. I do that by addressing the columns on my data frame using the vector `c(1:2, 6, 3:5)` which is equivalent to `c(1, 2, 6, 3, 4, 5)`.

```
> dataset <- dataset[,c(1:2, 6, 3:5)]
> dataset
  c1 c2 c2b c3 c4 c5
1  1  2  10  3  4  5
2  2  3  11  4  5  6
3  3  4  12  5  6  7
4  4  5  13  6  7  8
5  5  6  14  7  8  9
```

There!

Answer (score 4):

You would like to add column z to the old data frame (old.df)
defined by columns x and y.

```
z = rbinom(1000, 5, 0.25)
old.df <- data.frame(x = c(1:1000), y = rnorm(1:1000))
head(old.df)
```

Define a new data frame called new.df

```
new.df <- data.frame(x = old.df[,1], z, y = old.df[,2])
head(new.df)
```

Answer (score 4):

Easy solution. In a data frame with 5 columns, If you want insert another column between 3 and 4...

```
tmp <- data[, 1:3]
tmp$example <- NA # or any value.
data <- cbind(tmp, data[, 4:5]
```

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I wrote a function to do this:

[removed]

---

I have now updated this function with `before` and `after` functionality and defaulting `place` to 1. It also has data table compatability:

```
#####
# FUNCTION: InsertDFCol(colName, colData, data, place = 1, before, after)
# DESCRIPTION: Takes in a data, a vector of data, a name for that vector and a place to insert this vector into
# the data frame as a new column. If you put place = 3, the new column will be in the 3rd position and push the current
# 3rd column up one (and each subsuquent column up one). All arguments must be set. Adding a before and after
# argument that will allow the user to say where to add the new column, before or after a particular column.
# Please note that if before or after is input, it WILL override the place argument if place is given as well. Also, place
# defaults to adding the new column to the front.
#####

InsertDFCol <- function(colName, colData, data, place = 1, before, after) {

  # A check on the place argument.
  if (length(names(data)) < place) stop("The place argument exceeds the number of columns in the data for the InsertDFCol function. Please check your place number")
  if (place <= 0 & (!missing(before) | !(missing(after)))) stop("You cannot put a column into the 0th or less than 0th position. Check your place argument.")
  if (place %% 1 != 0 & (!missing(before) | !(missing(after)))) stop("Your place value was not an integer.")
  if (!(missing(before)) & !missing(after)) stop("You cannot designate a before AND an after argument in the same function call. Please use only one or the other.")

  # Data Table compatability.
  dClass <- class(data)
  data <- as.data.frame(data)

  # Creating booleans to define whether before or after is given.
  useBefore <- !missing(before)
  useAfter <- !missing(after)

  # If either of these are true, then we are using the before or after argument, run the following code.
  if (useBefore | useAfter) {

    # Checking the before/after argument if given. Also adding regular expressions.
    if (useBefore) { CheckChoice(before, names(data)) ; before <- paste0("^", before, "$") }
    if (useAfter) { CheckChoice(after, names(data)) ; after <- paste0("^", after, "$") }

    # If before or after is given, replace "place" with the appropriate number.
    if (useBefore) { newPlace <- grep(before, names(data)) ; if (length(newPlace) > 1) { stop("Your before argument matched with more than one column name. Do you have duplicate column names?!") }}
    if (useAfter) { newPlace <- grep(after, names(data)) ; if (length(newPlace) > 1) { stop("Your after argument matched with more than one column name. Do you have duplicate column names?!") }}
    if (useBefore) place <- newPlace # Overriding place.
    if (useAfter) place <- newPlace + 1 # Overriding place.

  }

  # Making the new column.
  data[, colName] <- colData

  # Finding out how to reorder this.
  # The if statement handles the case where place = 1.
  currentPlace <- length(names(data)) # Getting the place of our data (which should have been just added at the end).
  if (place == 1) {

    colOrder <- c(currentPlace, 1:(currentPlace - 1))

  } else if (place == currentPlace) { # If the place to add the new data was just at the end of the data. Which is stupid...but we'll add support anyway.

    colOrder <- 1:currentPlace

  } else { # Every other case.

    firstHalf <- 1:(place - 1) # Finding the first half on columns that come before the insertion.
    secondHalf <- place:(currentPlace - 1) # Getting the second half, which comes after the insertion.
    colOrder <- c(firstHalf, currentPlace, secondHalf) # Putting that order together.

  }

  # Reordering the data.
  data <- subset(data, select = colOrder)

  # Data Table compatability.
  if (dClass[1] == "data.table") data <- as.data.table(data)

  # Returning.
  return(data)

}
```

---

I realized I also did not include CheckChoice:

```
#####
# FUNCTION: CheckChoice(names, dataNames, firstWord == "Oops" message = TRUE)                                                                                               
# DESCRIPTION: Takes the column names of a data frame and checks to make sure whatever "choice" you made (be it 
# your choice of dummies or your choice of chops) is actually in the data frame columns. Makes troubleshooting easier. 
# This function is also important in prechecking names to make sure the formula ends up being right. Use it after 
# adding in new data to check the "choose" options. Set firstWord to the first word you want said before an exclamation point.
# The warn argument (previously message) can be set to TRUE if you only want to 
#####

CheckChoice <- function(names, dataNames, firstWord = "Oops", warn = FALSE) {

  for (name in names) {

    if (warn == TRUE) { if(!(name %in% dataNames)) { warning(paste0(firstWord, "! The column/value/argument, ", name, ", was not valid OR not in your data! Check your input! This is a warning message of that!")) } }
    if (warn == FALSE) { if(!(name %in% dataNames)) { stop(paste0(firstWord, "! The column/value/argument, " , name, ", was not valid OR not in your data! Check your input!")) } }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would simply use `cbind()` for this:

```
> df <- data.frame(a=1:5,
+                  b=10:14,
+                  c=rep(0,5),
+                  d=7:11)
> 
> z <- LETTERS[1:5]
> df <- cbind(df[,1:2], z, df[,3:4]) # Puts the z column between 2nd and 3rd column of df
> df
  a  b z c  d
1 1 10 A 0  7
2 2 11 B 0  8
3 3 12 C 0  9
4 4 13 D 0 10
5 5 14 E 0 11
```

Answer (score 1):

This function inserts one zero column between all  pre-existent columns in a data frame.

```
insertaCols<-function(dad){   
  nueva<-as.data.frame(matrix(rep(0,nrow(daf)*ncol(daf)*2 ),ncol=ncol(daf)*2))  
   for(k in 1:ncol(daf)){   
      nueva[,(k*2)-1]=daf[,k]   
      colnames(nueva)[(k*2)-1]=colnames(daf)[k]  
      }  
   return(nueva)   
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a an example of how to move a column from last to first position. It combines `[` with `ncol`. I thought it would be useful to have a very short answer here for the busy reader:

```
d = mtcars
d[, c(ncol(d), 1:(ncol(d)-1))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `append()` function to insert items into vectors or lists (dataframes are lists). Simply:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2), b=c(3,4), c=c(5,6))

df <- as.data.frame(append(df, list(d=df$b+df$c), after=2))
```

Or, if you want to specify the position by name use `which`:

```
df <- as.data.frame(append(df, list(d=df$b+df$c), after=which(names(df)=="b")))
```

Answer (score 0):

`

```
data1 <- data.frame(col1=1:4, col2=5:8, col3=9:12)
row.names(data1) <- c("row1","row2","row3","row4")
data1
data2 <- data.frame(col1=21:24, col2=25:28, col3=29:32)
row.names(data2) <- c("row1","row2","row3","row4")
data2
insertPosition = 2
leftBlock <- unlist(data1[,1:(insertPosition-1)])
insertBlock <- unlist(data2[,1:length(data2[1,])])
rightBlock <- unlist(data1[,insertPosition:length(data1[1,])])
newData <- matrix(c(leftBlock, insertBlock, rightBlock), nrow=length(data1[,1]), byrow=FALSE)
newData
```

`

Answer (score 0):

R has no functionality to specify where a new column is added. E.g., `mtcars$mycol<-'foo'`. It always is added as last column. Using other means (e.g., `dplyr's select()`) you can move the mycol to a desired position. This is not ideal and R may want to try to change that in the future.

Comment: Yes, it has the `append` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below -

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:4, b=5:8, c=9:12)
df['d'] <- seq(10,13)
df <- df[,c('a','b','d','c')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2), b=c(3,4), c=c(5,6))
df %>%
  mutate(d= a/2) %>%
  select(a, b, d, c)
```

results

```
  a b   d c
1 1 3 0.5 5
2 2 4 1.0 6
```

I suggest to use `dplyr::select` after `dplyr::mutate`. It has many helpers to select/de-select subset of columns.

In the context of this question the order by which you select will be reflected in the output data.frame.

Answer (score 0):

When you can not assume that column `b` comes before `c` you can use `match` to find the column number of both, `min` to get the lower column number and `seq_len` to get a sequence until this column. Then you can use this index first as a *positive* subset, than place the new column `d` and then use the sequence again as a *negative* subset.

```
i <- seq_len(min(match(c("b", "c"), colnames(x))))
data.frame(x[i], d, x[-i])
#cbind(x[i], d, x[-i]) #Alternative
#  a b  d c
#1 1 4 10 7
#2 2 5 11 8
#3 3 6 12 9
```

In case you know that column `b` comes before `c` you can place the new column `d` after `b`:

```
i <- seq_len(match("b", colnames(x)))
data.frame(x[i], d, x[-i])
#  a b  d c
#1 1 4 10 7
#2 2 5 11 8
#3 3 6 12 9
```

Data:

```
x <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6, c = 7:9)
d <- 10:12
```