# Is there a simple function that allows you to move one column in between or after another column

Tags: r

I am looking for something like from this posting

[Add (insert) a column between two columns in a data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13502601/add-insert-a-column-between-two-columns-in-a-data-frame)

```
add_column(dataset, d = 4:8, .after = 2)
```

However i am not trying to "add" but move, is there something similar like which will remove the original location of the file and keep the update

```
move_column(dataset, d = 4:8, .after = 2)
```

Comment: can't you add it and remove the original?

Comment: I could but then they have the same names. I could rename and add, but i was wondering if this can just be avoided and written in one line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like [relocate](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/relocate.html) in the dplyr package, which is part of tidyverse

```
df_new<- dataset %>%
   relocate(mycolumn, .after = the_other_column)
```

Comment: `tidyverse` is pretty huge at this point, it would be nice to point out which package this is from (`dplyr`, I think).

Answer (score 1):

A possible way:

```r
move_column <- function(dataset, d, .after)
{
  remaining <- setdiff(1:ncol(dataset), c(d, 1:.after))
  dataset[,c(1:.after, d, remaining)]
}

head(mtcars)
#>                mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1

head(move_column(mtcars, d = 4:5, .after = 2))
#>                mpg cyl  hp drat disp    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4     21.0   6 110 3.90  160 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6 110 3.90  160 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710    22.8   4  93 3.85  108 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
```